# How to format the text in a column using displaytag?

Tags: displaytag

I am having a problem in display tag. In my application am having a drop down list called "city" with different values hyd, b'lore,and etc.
    So when we select one option from the city drop down list and click on submit then a table data is displayed using display tag.
    The data is displaying after i click submit button but the data is not properly formatted.Hw can i format the text in that column..?

```
description(displaying the data like this) 
--------------
aaaa
aaaaa
a
aaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaa
aaaaaa
aa
aaaaaaaaaaaa

description(i want the data to be like this)
----------
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaa

    That is actually the data can be adjusted in maximum of 3-4 lines but here the data is adjusted inin morethan 6-7 lines. 
This is only happening with only one particular record.. Hw can i do this??
```

I wrote the tag like this:

```
<display:column property="description" style="width:2%;white-space:nowrap;"  class="normalfont"/>
```

Can any body suggest me what more values can i use in style attribute of display tag to format the text..

Comment: can i use display: inline or display:block in style attribute to format the text? I used it, but there is no change in the format of data..

Comment: i tried, style= "word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all" but the data is not formatting properly..

Comment: I used different values for style attribute like,

style=white-space:nowrap / normal / pre / pre-line / pre-wrap / inherit;
sytle=word-wrap:break-word;
style=word-break:break-all;

But the text format is not changing correctly... Please suggest me if some more values are there to format the text.

Thanks,
Vidya

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxLength="integer"`. I t will make a text as

> description(displaying the data like this)
>
> ---
>
> aaaaa...
>
> aaaaa...
>
> aaaaa...

Use as below

```
<display:column property="description" style="width:2%;white-space:nowrap;"  class="normalfont" maxLength="40"/>
```